# Remove custom module's subpanel in SugarCRM 7.x

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I'm looking to remove a custom module's (pc_songs) subpanel from the Opportunities subpanel area.

I've looked in modules/Opportunities/clients/base/layouts/subpanels/subpanels.php
The pc_songs subpanel isn't in the array.

I've also looked in modules/Opportunities/metadata/subpaneldefs.php
I don't see an entry for pc_songs here either.

The subpanel does show up in the detail view. Can anyone show me how to remove/hide a custom subpanel or even point me to where custom modules are added to the stock subpanel array?

Comment: Is it that you want to remove this subpanel just from the Opportunities module, or all modules? There's a setting in admin for the latter.

Comment: @Reisclef I want to remove this subpanel just for the Opportunities module.

Comment: Hi @msalo455, did my answer help?

Comment: @reisclef Yes, it worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SugarCRM 7, custom subpanels are stored in the following directory:

custom/Extension/modules/{module}/Ext/clients/base/layouts/subpanels

You will probably see a file akin to pc_songs_opportunities_Opportunities.php

If you want it to not display, please try to either:

- Remove the file
- Comment out the code in the file
- create a "disabled" directory, and place the file inside

After you do that, go to Admin -> Repair -> Quick Repair and Rebuild, and your subpanel should no longer display in Opportunities.

Here's the [Documentation](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.7/Data_Framework/Subpanels/) on subpanels in 7.7.

Answer (score 1):

Subpanels can also be easily hidden via the Administration panel. You can decide what modules appear in subpanels or in the main app navigation header.

Comment: Side-Note: While this is great for stopping a module from showing up as subpanel _anywhere_, it does not allow you any fine-grained control.
You cannot use this feature to hide the subpanel in a _particular_ module only.